# Trouble using PDO for the first time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get started with PDO and am having some trouble. Here's my original code:

```
    $query = "
              UPDATE `products` 
              SET `product_qty` = '{$_GET['product_qty']}'
              WHERE `product_id` = '{$_GET['product_id']}'
    ";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

That works fine, but when I try to translate that to PDO syntax:

```
    $db->prepare('
    UPDATE products 
    SET product_qty = :product_qty
    WHERE product_id = :product_id
    ');

    try 
    {
        $db->execute(array(':product_qty' => $_GET['product_qty'], ':product_id' => $_GET['product_id']));
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
```

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in ...

Could someone help me get my first PDO query working?

Comment: Upvoted for taking the time to switch to PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$db->prepare()` returns a `PDOStatement` which has the `execute()` method.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE products 
    SET product_qty = :product_qty
    WHERE product_id = :product_id');

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':product_qty' => $_GET['product_qty'], 
    ':product_id' => $_GET['product_id']
));
```

Answer (score 4):

`$db->prepare()` returns a `PDOStatement` object. You need to call `execute()` on that, not on `$db`.

Answer (score 1):

I refer ya to the example... the prepare creates a statement, and it's that that you run execute() on...

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `prepare` returns a `PDOStatement`, it is this that you need to `execute`. Try the following:

```
$sth = $db->prepare('
  UPDATE products 
  SET product_qty = :product_qty
  WHERE product_id = :product_id
');

$sth->execute(array(':product_qty' => $_GET['product_qty'], ':product_id' => $_GET['product_id']));
```